# Before I ask: Questions asking for book suggestion

Tags: support, on-topic

Is it On-topic to ask for suggestions for books related to sports, like I am looking for a newer edition or book similar to The Oxford Companion to Sports and Games, (I have a 1976 edition of it)?

Just being careful since I'm new here!

Comment: This older post is, to some extent, related: [Are questions about lists of references or online resources on topic?](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/394/are-questions-about-lists-of-references-or-online-resources-on-topic)

Comment: @Martin, thanks! edmastermind29 has made it clear that I can't. Anyway, I will try searching for some similar SEs/other sites. I strongly disagree to SEs restricting the scope of question in their field  itself. Math.SE is very liberal in that case, if the question is well quoted. Otherwise sites should be properly named, you can't say sports and restrict people from asking questions about sports. Imagine a new user (I knew Meta, hence first asked here) asking it in main site - he will be showered with downvotes, never to return again!

Comment: Even if the question is off-topic on main, you can still ask in chat. (Although, since there are not too many active users, it is not very probably that you get an answer. But the same is true about the main site.) And I do not think that a user posting such a question here would be "showered with downvotes". Maybe they would get one or two downvotes and the question would be closed. (At this stage, people do not vote that much on this site - e.g., there are only 3 users with [electorate badge](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate) at the moment.)

Comment: Although the only book recommendation question I was able to find on the main has score -6 at the moment: http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/726/any-recommend-jos%C3%A9-mourinho-biography-book

Comment: BTW I have mentioned your book recommendation request [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22042968#22042968). We will see whether you will have some luck and get some responses.

Comment: @Martin, I am sorry I sounded a bit unpleasant. I should understand the site is at present building a community, and possibly in future may change rules, once there are people who don't mind answering such questions. Anyway, I'll try my luck elsewhere! :) Thank you for explaining them!

Answer (score 2):

This should cover what you are looking for: [How to request book recommendations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/how-to-request-book-recommendations)

TL;DR - these types of questions are [not a good fit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113684) for any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I come from Math SE, and we allow such questions there, if asked properly. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @edmastermind29 - I reversed the migration to Meta.SE. Pretty sure the OP is asking about the policy on Sports specifically so they don't break any rules before posting.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks. As you can see, I already provided that. I wanted to turn over every stone for the OP.